# Multiple Pins on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps

I am trying to get a map to have multiple pins. These locations are loaded through a while loop. The map only shows the initial location though.

```
echo "
    <div class ='map' id ='map' style='border-style: solid; height:400px;'></div>
";

echo "
<div class='list-group'>
 ";

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        extract($row);
        $new_lat = $row['gps_lat'];
        $new_long = $row['gps_long'];
        $distance_to_the_point = haversineGreatCircleDistance ($original_gps_lat, $original_gps_long, $new_lat, $new_long);
        if ($distance_to_the_point <= $radius)
        {
        echo"
        <script>
            var longs = [];
            var lats = [];
            lats.push(".$row['gps_lat'].");
            longs.push(".$row['gps_long'].");
        </script>";
```

...`Some logic code`...

```
echo "</div>
<script>
    function initialize() 
    {
        myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(31.5852, -85.2308);
        var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: myLatlng
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < longs.length; i++) {  
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lats[i], longs[i]),
        map: map
      });

        }

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>";
```

I appreciate any help available. I am getting no error in code and the console is showing that the markers are getting the right long and lat. This is coded in php and echoed into the DOM into the browser for security purposes.

Comment: You need to initialize all the markers inside the initialize function (your map variable is local to that function)

Comment: @geocodezip I updated my code and still does not show any pins. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your `map` variable before you use it to create the markers.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/k7qes3fa/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var longs = [];
var lats = [];
lats.push(31.5);
longs.push(-85.2);
lats.push(31.5852);
longs.push(-85.2308)

function initialize() {
  myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(31.5852, -85.2308);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: myLatlng
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
  for (var i = 0; i < longs.length; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(lats[i], longs[i]),
      map: map
    });
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div class='map' id='map'></div>
<div class='list-group'>
```